# Remove items in a list and append new items with jquery

Tags: jquery, replace, append

I have the following output:

```
<ul id="blogs">

  <li>
      <a href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">
      <div class="video-container">...</div>
     </a>
 </li>

   <a href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">
   <strong id="title">Hurricane Sandy</strong>
   <p id="newsp">loremi ispum lor ismi smodi</p>
   </a>
 <a id="readp" class="rmore" href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">Read More</a>

 <li>
   <a href="/blogs/news/6572743-floyd"></a>
   <div class="video-container">...</div>
   </a>
</li>

  <a href="/blogs/news/6572743-floyd"></a>
  <strong id="title">Hurricane Floyd</strong>
  <p id="newsp">loremi ispum lor ismi smodi</p>
  </a>
   <a id="readp" class="rmore" href="/blogs/news/6572743-floyd">Read More</a>


  <li>
  <a href="/blogs/news/6557987-fiji">
   <img li="" ...<="" src="//mydomain/A21E1A04F48C9B7F42333F72EB5A57D9.jpg?932">
    <strong id="title">Fiji.</strong>
   <p id="newsp">loremi ispum lor ismi smodi</p>
  </a>
   <a id="readp" class="rmore" href="/blogs/news/6557987-fiji">Read More</a>
  </li>


   </ul>
```

I would like to edit my output above with jQuery to look like the following:

```
<ul id="blogs">
  <li>
     <a href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">
      <img src="http://mydomain/video_icons.jpg?1212">
     </a>
     <strong id="title">Hurricane Sandy</strong>
     <p id="newsp">loremi ispum lor ismi smodi</p>
     <a id="readp" class="rmore" href="/blogs/news/6875583-hurricane-sandy">Read More</a>
  </li>

  <li>
      <a href="/blogs/news/6572743-floyd"></a>
      <img src="http://mydomain/video_icons.jpg?1212">
     </a>
     <strong id="title">Hurricane Floyd</strong>
     <p id="newsp">loremi ispum lor ismi smodi</p>
     <a id="readp" class="rmore" href="/blogs/news/6572743-floyd">Read More</a>
  </li>

  <li>
     <a href="/blogs/news/6557987-fiji">
      <img src="//mydomain/A21E1A04F48C9B7F42333F72EB5A57D9.jpg?932">
     </a>
    <strong id="title">Fiji.</strong>
    <p id="newsp">loremi ispum lor ismi smodi</p>
    <a id="readp" class="rmore" href="/blogs/news/6557987-fiji">Read More</a>
```

This is my jQuery but I missing something or not writing this correctly so I am not getting the desired output:

jQuery:

```
 $("#blogs li").each(function(i) {
    if ($(".video-container").length > 0  && $(this).children('img').length == 0){
      var vidindex = $('#readp').attr('href')
      $(this).find('a').replaceWith(function(){return '';});
      $(".video-container").remove();
      $(this).append('<a href=""><img src="{{ 'video_icons.jpg' | asset_url }}"/></a>');
      $(this).append($("#title"));
      $(this).append($('#newsp'));
      $(this).append($('#readp'))
      $(this).find('a').attr("href", vidindex)
  }
     $("#blogs li img").replaceWith(function(){
     return '<img src="'+this.src+'"/>';
   });
});
```

Comment: Well, I don't use template tags, but the thing that pops out right away is that you're not escaping the interpreter at `'video_icons.jpg'`. It should be `'+video_icons.jpg+'` if that's some variable, or it should be `{{ \"video_icons.jpg\" | asset_url }}`. But, if that's a string, then you shouldn't even need to escape it whatsoever.

Comment: It seems as if it doesn't cycle through my for loop properly

Comment: Your markup is invalid, IDs must be unique. Also note that you're replacing images in each iteration again and again.

Comment: Ahh...I see what's wrong. You're using the same `ID` over and over, so when you reference it in the DOM it's only taking into consideration the LAST element rendered with that ID. You need to change those ID's to classes, and use either `$('.readp', this)` or `$(this).find('.readp')`. As it stands, the ID propagation is your biggest issue. I would also look at the interpreter escaping as that video_icons.jpg will never render right and will throw errors in the console, like `unexepected ' on line whatever in whatever.js`